# AdMob adrequest going crazy?

Tags: android, admob

So the past day something strange is happening with my AdMob ads.

First you should know that we usually know when someone is using our Android app because it sends their score to our server right after they are finished.

So no one appears to be using it and all of a sudden the requests keep going up and up without any clicks. Desperate to save my relatively high click through rate (CTR), I disable refresh hoping that it was just someone who left their phone on and the screen was not sleeping. This, however, did nothing and the requests keep coming in at the writing of this.

Has anyone experienced something similar? I am thinking it is maybe a glitch or maybe AdMob purposely screwing up my CTR? Everything was fine for the past 2 weeks until now.

Update: it stopped after about 8 hours of continuous ad requests and impressions. The cause is still unknown. But my CTR has suffered because of it and is now below 1 percent. Hopefully this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Are you perhaps calling `adView.loadAd(new AdRequest())` in `onFailedToReceiveAd`, or manually refreshing at some other point in your app?  Are impressions really high too, or just requests?

Comment: I do not call loadAd in onFailedtoReceiveAd and I do not implement any refresh code in my app. Impressions and requests are both about the same (impressions a little less). It ended up stopping (see above edit).